# Why doesn't this generate sudoku puzzles with unique solutions?

Tags: javascript, sudoku

I built a program that creates sudoku puzzles, but found that the solutions weren't always unique, so I implemented a solver to try and check that.

My `unique()` function returns that the puzzles I generate are correct, but when I check them in [this website](https://www.thonky.com/sudoku/solution-count?puzzle=) and when I solve them manually it (sometimes) shows otherwise, especially when `numOfFilledTiles` is less than ~45.

I can't tell what about my functions doesn't work... I would love some help!

(I'm using a `Cell` class that has a `value` property)

```
const bestBet = (emptyCells) => {
    let cellIndex;
    let bestLength = 10;
    for(let i = 0; i < emptyCells.length; i++){
        let moves = getMoves(emptyCells[i]); //getMoves() returns all of a cell's legal options
        if(moves.length < bestLength){
            bestLength = moves.length;
            cellIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return cellIndex;
}

const stringify = (arr) => {
    let string = '';
    for(let x of arr){
        string += x.value;
    }
    return string;
}

const solve = (cells /*an array of all the cell objects*/) => {
    let emptyCells = cells.filter(cell => cell.value === 0);
    if(emptyCells.length === 0) return stringify(cells);
    let bestCell = bestBet(emptyCells);
    let moves = getMoves(cells[bestCell]);
    for(let move of moves){
        cells[bestCell].value = move;
        if(solve(cells)) return stringify(cells);
    }
    cells[bestCell].value = 0;
    return false;
}

const unique = (cells) => {
    //filling in all cells that have just one option
    let singleSolutions = cells.filter(cell => cell.value === 0 && getMoves(cell).length === 1);
    for(let cell of singleSolutions){
        cell.value = getMoves(cell)[0];
    }

    const possibleSolutions = [];
    let emptyCells = cells.filter(cell => cell.value === 0);
    for(let cell of emptyCells){
        let moves = getMoves(cell);
        for(let move of moves){
            cell.value = move;
            possibleSolutions.push(solve(cells));
            if (Array.from(new Set(possibleSolutions)).length > 1 ) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

const createPuzzle = (cells, numOfFilledCells) => {
    const full = [];
    let indexes = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 81; i++){
        full.push(i);
        indexes.push(i);
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < 81 - numOfFilledCells; i++){
        if(indexes.length === 0){
            //in case we've got too many undeletable cells
            indexes = full.slice();
            i = 0;
            for(let cell of cells){
                cell.reveal();
                cell.deletable = true;
            }
        }
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * indexes.length);
        let selectedCell = cells[indexes[rand]];
        if(!selectedCell.deletable){
            i--;
        } else {
            selectedCell.hide();
            if(!unique(cells, rows, columns, boxes)){
                selectedCell.reveal();
                selectedCell.deletable = false;
                i--;
            }
        }
        indexes.splice(rand, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to clear the value of a cell after attempting to assign a value to it?

Comment: @mousetail if I understand you correctly - don't I do this after the for loop in `solve()`? `bestCell.value = 0`? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Your title says that the problem is generating unique puzzles. But the question text says that the problem is with solving them.

Comment: @Barmar the problem is with generating them ***uniquely***. As the title says, the problem is that the puzzles that are coming out aren't unique. To verify that they're unique, a solver is needed.

Comment: Sounds like we're using a different definition of unique. To me it means "not a duplicate of one of the other puzzles"

Comment: @Barmar edited to make the title clearer

Comment: Thanks, I just figured out that's what you meant.

Comment: It's often helpful to see how others have solved the same problem:  See: [javascript sudoku puzzle questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sudoku+javascript) on SO.

Comment: thank you @Yogi, looked through it and found the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

## Found a solution!

Instead of checking if there are multiple solutions via an array, I checked for multiple solution by using a counter to count them.

This works really well, and generates puzzles with fully unique solutions! (It also removes the need for the `stringify()` function which I rather appreciate.)

However, this function crashes if `numOfFilledTiles` is below 24. I presume it might have to do with me not properly breaking recursion when there is more than one answer. It also just takes a noticeable amount of time when `numOfFilledTiles` is below 30.

Here is my fixed code:

```
const unique = (cells) => {
    let counter = 0;
    const solve = (cells) => {
        let emptyCells = cells.filter(cell => cell.value === 0);
        if(emptyCells.length === 0){
            counter++;
            return false;
        }
        let bestCell = bestBet(emptyCells);
        let moves = getMoves(emptyCells[bestCell]);
        for(let m of moves){
            emptyCells[bestCell].value = m;
            if(solve(cells) && counter < 2) return true;
        }
        emptyCells[bestCell].value = 0;
        return false;
    }
    solve(cells);
    if(counter > 1) return false;
    return true;
}
```

(`bestBet()` and `createPuzzle()` work the same as in the question. I also removed the `singleSolutions` bit - it was causing me a load of trouble and it wasn't worth the effort, imo)